# Is it possible to change SVN hosting and preserve the revision history?

Tags: svn, revision, svnadmin, svn-administraton

Question as in title. I'd like to change my SVN hosting - can I move my project to another one and not lose the revision (change) history?

Comment: Yes, you can. What have you tried?

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2013? Please, upvote and accept it then. :)

Comment: @bahrep I honestly don't remember this anymore. I think contacting the hosting provider might not have been an option and I haven't tried `svnrdump`. I will upvote it but can't accept it.

Comment: @NPS got it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Your SVN hosting provider should be able to provide you with a [repository dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnadmin) so you could load it to another hosting or your in-house Subversion server. However you may need to contact hosting support to get the dump. BTW in a hosting control panel it can be referred as a *repository backup*.

The other solution would be to use [`svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnrdump) tool that can get repository dump remotely.

I advise you to consider reading SVNBook on this matter: [Migrating Repository Data Elsewhere](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate).